# Setup PM2 LogRotate using Ecosystem JS File

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, pm2, pm2-logrotate

I am currently using a PM2 ecosystem file `ecosystem.config.js` to start multiple Node.js apps using PM2.

```
module.exports = 
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "script": "./foo.js",
    },
    {
      "name": "bar",
      "script": "./bar.js",
    },
    {
      "name": "baz",
      "script": "./baz.js",
    }
  ]
}
```

If we want to [setup `logrotate` PM2 module](https://github.com/keymetrics/pm2-logrotate#configure) to rotate my log files, instead of manually running the commands

```
pm2 set pm2-logrotate:max_size 1K 
pm2 set pm2-logrotate:compress true
pm2 set pm2-logrotate:rotateInterval '*/1 * * * *'
```

can the `logrotate` settings be configured using the ecosystem JS file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **not possible**. Based on `pm2-logrotate` author:

> It's not possible apparently since pm2-logrotate is different than pm2, pm2 is not aware beforehand if pm2-lr is already installed or not.

Source: https://github.com/keymetrics/pm2-logrotate/issues/131